# Why does VLOOKUP only works once per row?

Tags: google-sheets, vlookup, importrange

I have a VLOOKUP & IMPORTRANGE formula that works great on the first cell I use it on.  When I try to use it on another cell the IMPORTRANGE fails (I assume) and I get an error:

> Error Did not find value '21' in VLOOKUP evaluation.

The INDIRECT function is working and the error states the correct value I am searching for.

Code:

```
=VLOOKUP(INDIRECT("B" & ROW()),IMPORTRANGE("XXX","YYY!A1:E500"),5,false)
```

It should work on multiple rows, but it only works on the first row.  Is there a Sheets limitation I am not aware of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

continuity is secured by **`ARRAYFORMULA`**. try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(INDIRECT("B" & ROW()), IMPORTRANGE("URL-ID", "YYY!A1:E500"), 5, 0))
```

you may want to wrap it in **`IFERROR()`** to avoid **`#N/A!`**